# A jar file can rename or delete itself at run time?

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm looking a solution to rename or delete a jar file by itself at run time. I have some tries such as using a batch file which runs script to rename the jar file just before System.exit(0) command:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("********start jar file*****");
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.bat");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The batch file is contain below scripts:

```
cd c:\users\user
ren "path to jar file" newName.jar
```

But, it cannot rename the jar file.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being daft here, but why on earth do you think you want to do this?

Comment: The JVM has the jar file locked, can't be deleted or renamed.

Comment: I want to update the jar file at run time. I have an app (jar file) and i want to get new version of it, remotely. Then replacing the new version on the old version which is running now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a wrapper script. Write a program (another jar, if you so wish) that the user launches which launches your application then exits if there isn’t a new version. If there is a new version available, delete the old one, download the new one, then start the new one and exit the launcher.

Comment: Also, I do it only by some scripts in a batch. We can pass the process ID of current main jar (which is running now) to the batch file as an argument, killing it with force option, and then replacing new_version of our jar.